# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable upon incorrect speech recognition

Tags: python, voice-recognition, espeak

I'm working on a TTS/STT system for a school project and it was going well until I started getting this specific error whenever the code ran through the "Google Speech Recognition Does not recognize what you said" bit. I am unsure of why I get this specific error. The python libraries that I am using are just the espeak,speech recognition, and pyaudio libraries. My code is below.

```
from subprocess import call
import speech_recognition as sr
import serial
r = sr.Recognizer()
import os,time
def listen1():
    with sr.Microphone(device_index = 2) as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            print("Please speak.");
            audio = r.listen(source)
            print("Heard.");
    return audio
def voice(audio1):
    try:
        text1 = r.recognize_google(audio1)
        ##call('espeak ' +text, shell=True)
        print("You said: " +text1);
        return text1;
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        call(["espeak", "-a 200 -v en+1 ", "Google Speech Recognition did not recognize what you said."])
        print("Google Speech Recognition did not recognize what you said.")
        return 0
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results fromm Google")
        return 0
def main(text):
    audio1 = listen1()
    text = voice(audio1)  
    if 'hello' in text:
        call(["espeak", "-a 200 -v en+1" , "Hi, how are you"])
    if 'good' in text:
        call(["espeak", "-a 200 -v en+1" , "Good to hear, now what will you have me do?"])
    if 'exit' in text:
        call(["espeak", "-a 200 -v en+1" , "Thank you, exiting."])
        exit()
    text = {}
    main(text)
if __name__ =='__main__':
 while(1):
    audio1=listen1()
    text = voice(audio1)
    if text == 'start':
        text = {}
        call(["espeak", "-a 200 -v en+1" ,"Hello, user, please say a commmand"])
        main(text)
    else:
        call(["espeak", "-a 200 -v en+1 " ,"Did not recognize command, repeat please?"])
```

What can I do to fix this error?
Thanks!

Comment: please post the full traceback of the error

Comment: When you get the error, your function `voice()`  returns 0 to the variable `text` in `main()`. That function does `if 'hello' in text:`. But you can't do an `in` test on 0 because it is an integer.

Comment: So if I wanted to make the main function recursive so I don’t have to fully greet the robot again, should I just call main() instead of main (text)? Or would I just add a return 0 statement right before calling main(text) again?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, when you get the error, your function `voice()` returns 0 to the variable text in `main()`. That function does `if 'hello' in text:`. But you can't do an in test on 0 because it is an integer.

Comment: So if I wanted to make the main function recursive so I don’t have to fully greet the robot again, should I just call main() instead of main (text)? Or would I just add a return 0 statement right before calling main(text) again?